# Django unicode is not working

Tags: python, django, unicode

im newbie at Python writing, and I'm trying to set up my database to manage it in django admin panel. My problem is that when i define unicode it's not working and I don't know why.

```
class Doors(models.Model):
door_uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
door_owner = models.IntegerField()
door_ownertype = models.IntegerField()
door_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Drzwi'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Drzwi'
    managed = True
    db_table = 'hrp_doors'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.door_uid
```

after doing it, it still shows 'HrpDoors object'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your indentation *exactly* is it is in your code.

Comment: it is exactly like I posted

Comment: No it isn't, because that is simply not valid Python: you would get `IndentationError` after the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `__unicode__` attribute is a method of `class Meta` where as it should be for `HrpDoors`

Try this:

```
class HrpDoors(models.Model):
    door_uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    door_owner = models.IntegerField()
    door_ownertype = models.IntegerField()
    door_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Drzwi'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Drzwi'
        managed = True
        db_table = 'hrp_doors'

    def __unicode__(self): #Look at the indentation of unicode - same level as attributes of class model
        return u'%s' % self.door_uid #Also, return unicode explicitly
```

Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode)

Comment: when I try to put definition at the same level as class, i get an indentation error

    def __unicode__(self):
                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: You cannot combine tabs and spaces in python. Keep it consistent - either 4 spaces all along, or tabs all along (PEP 8 recommends 4 spaces though.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about why you get an `HrpDoors` object.

You may have an indentation problem. Also your unicode function is returning an integer:

```
class HrpDoors(models.Model):
    door_uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.door_uid)
```